# Using a thread to repaint() components

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt

It doesn't appear that my thread ever starts. Either that or the `run` method isn't actually doing anything, for which reason I could not explain.

I have a listener on my button `StartRace` and it should start the thread which will increment the length of each rectangle until one of them is long enough to be declared winner (by surpassing the width of the window, 250px).

I get all of the components initially painted to the screen, but they're never repainted. Is there something wrong with the way I call the method? Do I have classes nested within others that shouldn't be?

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
//    Start a race between blue and red, track the winner
//    Use threads to manage each rectangle's movement
//    Allow for user interaction, like stopping and starting
//--------------------------------------------------------------


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ConcurrencyRace extends JFrame
{ 
   private ConcurrencyPanel panel = new ConcurrencyPanel(); 
   private JButton startRace = new JButton("Start The Race!");
   private JButton stopRace = new JButton("Stop The Race!");
   private JLabel winnerText = new JLabel("Winner: ");
   private int blueDraw = 5, redDraw = 5;
   private Random rn = new Random();

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates and displays the main program frame.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------

   public ConcurrencyRace() {
       super("Concurrency");
       setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Container cp = getContentPane();
       cp.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       JPanel p = new JPanel();
       p.add(startRace);
       p.add(stopRace);
       cp.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       cp.add(winnerText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       pack();
       setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       ConcurrencyRace tRun = new ConcurrencyRace();
       tRun.setVisible(true);
   }

   private class ConcurrencyPanel extends JPanel 
   {
       public class runnerThread extends Thread {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               while (blueDraw < 250 && redDraw < 250) {

                   panel.validate();
                   panel.repaint();

                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
               }
           }
       }

       public ConcurrencyPanel ()
       {
           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,250));

       }

       private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

           runnerThread rectDraw = new runnerThread();

           //--------------------------------------------------------------
           //  Starts the thread to draw each rectangle ("racer")
           //--------------------------------------------------------------
           public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
           {
               if (event.getSource() == startRace) {                   
                   rectDraw.start();
               }
           }
       }
       @Override
       public void paintComponent (Graphics page) {

           super.paintComponent(page);
           page.setColor(Color.blue);
           page.fillRect(0,80,blueDraw,20);

           page.setColor(Color.red);
           page.fillRect(0,120,redDraw,20);

           blueDraw += rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
           redDraw += rn.nextInt(10) + 1;

           page.dispose();
       }    
   }
}
```

Comment: Swing operations can only take place in the AWT event dispatch thread;  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.  Instead of creating a new thread, use a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead.  Also, do not call `dispose()` on a Graphics object you didn’t create—the Graphics instance passed to paint methods is managed by the AWT/Swing system.

Comment: Quit re-posting the same question -- this is abuse of this system, and is not fair to the volunteers who help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Primarily

You never add a `ActionListener` to either of your buttons, so nothing is responding when they are activated

## Additionally

1. The state management is all over the place.  `blueDraw` and `redDraw` should be instance fields of `ConcurrencyPanel`.
2. Don't update the state of the UI (or variables which the UI relies on) from within any paint method. Paint methods should paint the state, not change it. Updating the `blueDraw` and `redDraw` should be done in a specific method, which can be called when a update is required.

All of that leads me to believe you'd be better of using a Swing `Timer`

## Conceptually...

You could do something like this...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ConcurrencyRace {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Creates and displays the main program frame.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public ConcurrencyRace() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timer timer = new Timer(200, null);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ButtonPane(timer), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(new RacePane(timer));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConcurrencyRace();
    }

    public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton startRace = new JButton("Start The Race!");
        private JButton stopRace = new JButton("Stop The Race!");

        public ButtonPane(Timer timer) {
            startRace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timer.start();
                }
            });

            stopRace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(startRace);
            add(stopRace);
        }

    }

    private class RacePane extends JPanel {

        private int blueDraw = 5, redDraw = 5;
        private Random rn = new Random();

        public RacePane(Timer timer) {
            timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (updateState()) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected boolean updateState() {
            blueDraw += rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
            redDraw += rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
            repaint();

            return blueDraw >= getWidth() || redDraw >= getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 250);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
            System.out.println(">>");
            super.paintComponent(page);
            page.setColor(Color.blue);
            page.fillRect(0, 80, blueDraw, 20);

            page.setColor(Color.red);
            page.fillRect(0, 120, redDraw, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

This maintains the `Timer` as the central concept, which is shared between the buttons and race panels.

I've not added support for generating notification of a winner, this would be done via a simple observer pattern passed to the `RacePane`

Comment: I can't determine where to add the `ButtonListener`. If I try to do so within the `ConcurrencyPanel()` constructor it throws a bunch of errors. If I try to do it within the `ConcurrencyRace` constructor it doesn't recognize the `ButtonListener` class. As for `blueDraw` and `redDraw` you're saying declare them within `ConcurrencyPanel` and utilize a method to update their values? Would I do that after each tick of the `Timer`?

Comment: @mad: possible help vampire, but 1+ for your usual great answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your edit definitely helps me and makes perfect sense. I'll review it so that I understand the concept a bit more clearly.

Comment: It's pretty easy to print a winner notification to the screen, but how could I go about adding a label to the right of the stop button? I'd like to update that instead of printing a notification, but I don't know how I'd set the text of that label from the `RacePane`

Comment: @Steven As I said, you need some kind of observer pattern, `RacePane` would then generate a notification to the interested parties that the state has changed. If you're interested, the `ActionListener` and `Timer` is an example of a observer patten at work

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Just FYI, told this guy about Swing Timers a few days ago in a deleted question.